# My output seems to be looping or waiting for me to input twice before carrying on

Tags: java, loops, input

My output is this:

% Enter a positive integer: 90

% 90

% Enter another positive integer:

90 is the first integer I type in, but it doesn't automatically go to "enter another positive integer", why is that? Thanks in advance!

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
int a, b, r, x,temp;

for (int i = 0; i<10; i++){
   System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");
      while (true){
           while (!sc.hasNextInt()){
           sc.next();
           System.out.print("Please enter a positive integer: ");
           }if (sc.nextInt()<0){
               System.out.print("Please enter a positive integer: ");
           }else{
               a = sc.nextInt();
               break;
           }
      }


  System.out.print("Enter another positive integer: ");
       while(true){
            if (!sc.hasNextInt()){
            System.out.print("Please enter a positive integer: ");
            sc.next();
            }else if(sc.nextInt()>0){
                b = sc.nextInt();
                break;
            } else{
                System.out.print("Please enter a positive integer: ");
            }

       }
```

Comment: what do you this `while (!sc.hasNextInt()){` does?

Comment: It's so that as long as my next token is not an int, it will keep prompting me to 'try again'.

Comment: Have a look at this example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14411173/how-to-stop-reading-multiple-lines-from-stdin-using-scanner

Comment: Thanks, but if I tried out what was there and used sc.close(); my next statement is unreachable...

Comment: BTW there isn't a particular reason why the second loop is different, I was just testing out another method.

Comment: You should not be using `close` on a STDIN Scanner

Comment: `while` inside a `while` inside a `for`? Is this necessary?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the code will enter the first two `while` loops, and then the user needs to enter a number (`sc.next();`).

Then assuming the number is greater than 0, you go into your `else` statement, and you then call `a = sc.nextInt();`; therefore the user has to type in something else there.

And the same applies to the second loop.

Seeing as you wish to use `while` loops, you could do something like:

```
boolean flag;
System.out.print("Enter a positive integer: ");
int num;
do {
    flag = true;
    num = sc.nextInt();
    if (num < 0) {
        flag = false;
        System.out.print("Please enter a positive integer: ");
    }
} while (!flag);
```

and put that in your loop.

Regarding your comment above (*It's so that as long as my next token is not an int, it will keep prompting me to 'try again'*), this is not true as if you enter a non-digit, the program will crash. You could use a `try...catch` to ensure the number is a digit. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19925047/how-to-check-the-input-is-an-integer-or-not-in-java) for an example.

Answer (score 0):

Your first "90" entered in the System.in is consumed by the sc.nextInt() in the if statement. the second "90" entered is retrieved in the assignment statement a = sc.nextInt()

try changing to the following:

```
  while (true){
       while (!sc.hasNextInt()){
       sc.next();
       System.out.print("Please enter a positive integer: ");
       }
       a = sc.nextInt();
       if (a<0){
           System.out.print("Please enter a positive integer: ");
       }else{
           break;
       }
  }
```